# What are good free PBR material libraries for a beginner?

Tags: materials, pbr

I'm in the process of figuring out blender (on what could be considered my 3rd project I guess), and while browsing tutorials and youtube videos about blender, I've come across the topic of PBR materials, and have found it intriguing. I've found that using these materials makes my renders look a whole lot better than if I just slap a flat texture on the objects, but I'm a student and don't want to be spending money on this hobby just yet, which has run me into the issue that there aren't a whole lot of these materials out there that aren't reserved for some payed service. Do any of you know of any material libraries out there with PBR materials for free? So far I've been using the free materials on poliigon, and came across freepbr.com, but I can't figure out how to download any of the textures/maps from the latter of those two.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Ethan

Answer (score 1):

You should rather watch vidoes and try to create your own library so that u can learn as well. I would suggest you to watch videso from blender guru (https://youtu.be/V3wghbZ-Vh4) and remington graphics (https://youtu.be/OulP6f-aF-c). You can learn from these videos and create your own shaders. If not then i think remington has provided the shader pack for free as well.

Comment: The source for BG and Rem was CynicatPro, Andrew mentioned it. Also good material library was Wolf3D with easy to use addon. I write "was", because I don't like new version (3). 2 was better and it was nice for learning. 3 used principles shader :-(